# TypeScript unable to infer generic parameters of higher-order function depending on it's contents

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, higher-order-functions

Consider the following code:

```
let HOF1 = <Args, Ret>(f: (args: Args) => Ret) => {
    return (args: Args): Ret => {
        return f(args)
    }
}

let HOF2 = <Args, Ret>(f: (args: Args) => Ret) => {
    return <Result>(args: Args & { container: (args: Ret) => Result }) => {
        return args.container(f(args))
    }
}

let HOF3 = <Args, Ret>(f: (args: Args) => Ret) => {
    return 1
}

let take = <T>(args: { items: T[], n: number }) => args.items.slice(0, args.n)
let wrappedFn1 = HOF1(take)
let wrappedFn2 = HOF2(take)
let wrappedFn3 = HOF3(take)
```

All the higher-order functions HOF1, HOF2, and HOF3 have the same signature, and they are called with the same argument (the *take* function), and yet TypeScript (version 3.8.3) can only understand the first call. The last two lines generate a typing error. What could be wrong?

Comment: I'm unsure as to one part of the question; you say that all the `HOF`'s have the same signature, but they seem to me to be rather different.

Comment: @OliverRadini They all have the same signature, unless you're considering the return type as well. Normally return type is not considered when distinguishing signatures.